# Add Tab Dynamically Into A tabControl based on Selected item from ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, tabitem

I am working on MVVM sample app. I have 2 projects inside my solution in VSC# 2010. In one project (main project) I have a mainwindow.xaml which has two grids, one located on right side and other on the left. Left side grid has a listBox which has items with the help of observablecollection<>. E.g. Voltage, I2C etc are the items. I have also set the `selecteditem` property for the listbox which gives me the `selecteditem`.

My main query is the grid towards the right side which has a TABCONTROL with one item("CONNECT") added by default. What I need is to add the tabitem (e.g.Voltage tab) inside the tabcontrol when I select the "Voltage" item from listBox.

**TabControl and ListBox inside my grid:**

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Name="BoardTabSelect" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox Name="ButtonPanel" Style="{DynamicResource styleBanner}" ItemsSource="{Binding BoardTabs, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Name="BoardtabChanger" Margin="53,27,0,0" Text="{Binding TabOperation}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

My tabcontrol:

```
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                    <TabControl Name="ConnectTab" Style="{DynamicResource styleBackground}">
                        <tablocal:CloseableTabItem Header="Connect" x:Name="ConnectMain" MouseDoubleClick="TabItem_MouseDoubleClick"> 
                            <DockPanel>
                                <ListView  Name="listView" Height="460" Margin="0,-77,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <ListView.View>
                                        <GridView>
                                            <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                            <GridViewColumn Width="283" Header="Connection Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Connection_Status}" />
                                        </GridView>
                                    </ListView.View>
                                </ListView>

                                <Button Content="Connect" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-920,500,0,0" Name="ConnectBtnGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" Command="{Binding Path=ConnectCommand}" />
                                <Button Content="Update MSP430" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-560,500,0,0" Name="UpdateMSPBtn" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" />
                                <Button Content="Disconnect" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-220,500,0,0" Name="DisconnectBtn" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" Command="{Binding Path=DisconnectCommand}" />
                            </DockPanel>
                       </tablocal:CloseableTabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </Grid>
```

**My ViewModel class is here:**

```
public List<Product> m_Products;
    public ObservableCollection<Product> m_BoardTabs;        

    public ProductViewModel()
    {           
        m_Products = new List<Product>()
        {                
            new Product() {Name = "Bavaria", Connection_Status = "Disconnected"},
            new Product() {Name = "Redhook", Connection_Status = "Disconnected"},                
        };

        m_BoardTabs = new ObservableCollection<Product>()
        {
            new Product() {TabOperation = "Connect"}              
        };
    }                      

    public List<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Products;
        }

        set
        {
            m_Products = value;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> BoardTabs
    {
        get
        {
            return m_BoardTabs;
        }

        set
        {
            m_BoardTabs = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// get:
    /// set:   
    /// </summary>
    private Product m_SelectedItem;
    public Product SelectedProduct
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SelectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            m_SelectedItem = value;                
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedProduct");
        }
    }

    private Product m_SelectedTab;
    public Product SelectedTab
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SelectedTab;
        }

        set
        {
            m_SelectedTab = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTab");
            onTabChanged();
        }
    }        

    void onTabChanged()
    {
        if (SelectedTab.TabOperation == "Voltage")
        {
            //Add tab here
        }
    }

    public Product value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// get:
    /// set:   
    /// </summary>
    private ICommand mUpdater;
    public ICommand ConnectCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mUpdater == null)
                mUpdater = new DelegateCommand(new Action(SaveExecuted), new Func<bool>(SaveCanExecute));

            return mUpdater;
        }
        set
        {
            mUpdater = value;                
        }
    }

    public bool SaveCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }     

    public void SaveExecuted()
    {
        if (SelectedProduct.Connection_Status == "Disconnected" && SelectedProduct.Name == "Bavaria")
        {
            SelectedProduct.Connection_Status = "Connected";
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "I2C" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "Voltage" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "Clock" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "Codec" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "EEPROM" });                             
        }

        else if (SelectedProduct.Connection_Status == "Disconnected" && SelectedProduct.Name == "Redhook")
        {
            SelectedProduct.Connection_Status = "Connected";

            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "I2C" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "Voltage" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "Clock" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "Codec" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "EEPROM" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "PCM Route" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "PCM Route #" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "PCM Gen" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "SD Card" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "FPGA" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "PCMPDM" });
            m_BoardTabs.Add(new Product() { TabOperation = "Data Gen" });           
        }
    }
```

Mind you the tabitem "VOLTAGE" which I want to add in my control is part of another project which I mentioned in the beginning. It has its own view, viewmodel and model class. The following is the view in.xaml file which I want to add:

```
<Grid Name="VoltageTab" Height="572" Width="590" DataContext="{StaticResource VoltageViewModel}" >
    // Some UI componments which shud be placed inside VOLTAGE Tab on selecting Voltage from ListBox.
</Grid>
```

As you can see above, I want the above view to be placed inside the VoltageTab which should get created once user clicks Voltage item from ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data template for the tabcontrol should not contain a tabitem. The tabcontrol is generating a tabitem for each element in the bound Collection. To enable databinding to the tabitem header set the itemcontainerstyle property of the tabcontrol. Here is a small sample:

The View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfLab.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ProductTabs}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"/>
</Grid>
```

The ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfLab
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Product selectProduct;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            ProductTabs = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

            var products = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new Product { Header = "Product " + i });
            foreach (var p in products)
                Products.Add(p);

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public Product SelectedProduct 
        {
            get { return this.selectProduct; }

            set
            {
                UpdateTabs(this.selectProduct, value);
                this.selectProduct = value;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; private set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Product> ProductTabs { get; private set; }

        void UpdateTabs(Product old, Product @new)
        {
            if (ProductTabs.Any(p => p == old))
                ProductTabs.Remove(old);

            ProductTabs.Add(@new);
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Header;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don u think the content related to Product shud be in Product view model??
Where do i post this???"InitializeComponent();
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        ProductTabs = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
        var products = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new Product { Header = "Product " + i });
        foreach (var p in products)
            Products.Add(p);
        DataContext = this;

Comment: Absolutely! This is just an example to get you going in the right direction. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks per :) It adds the tab. But this is not a solution which I want. if you notice in my sample app, I have a tab which has CONNECT item which should be visible on startup so dat I can get the list of items into the listbox. Basically my default tabitem and listbox are binded. Check SaveExecuted() in my viewmodel and u will understand how my listbox and tabitem components are binded :)

Answer (score 0):

TabControl has an ItemsSource property.. this can be bound to an observable collection of objects from the ViewModel.

Along with this, the object being used in the observable collection must have an associated DataTemplate which should be a TabItem.

As a result, when you add an object to the ObservableCollection which acts as a source to your TabControl using the DataTemplate a new TabItem gets added to the TabControl.

Also make sure you have one entry / object in the observablecollection for the initial tabitem.

You can refer to the TabItem from the other project in the DataTemplate by adding appropriate namespace / references

Here is the ViewModel class

```
 public class TabItemDetail
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Members

    List<string> _dataSource = null;
    string _selectedDataSource = null;
    ObservableCollection<TabItemDetail> _tabItems = null;

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public ObservableCollection<TabItemDetail> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tabItems == null)
            {
                _tabItems = GetTabItems();
            }

            return _tabItems;
        }
    }

    public List<string> DataSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dataSource == null)
            {
                _dataSource = GetDataSource();
            }

            return _dataSource;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedDataSource
    {
        get { return _selectedDataSource; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedDataSource == value)
                return;

            _selectedDataSource = value;

            AddItemsToTab(value);

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDataSource");
        }
    }


    #region Private methods

    private void AddItemsToTab(string selectedItem)
    {
        if (_tabItems != null && _tabItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var query = from item in _tabItems
                        where item.Header == selectedItem
                        select item;

            if (query.Count() == 1)
                return;
            else
                _tabItems.Add(new TabItemDetail { Header = selectedItem });
        }
    }

    private List<string> GetDataSource()
    {
        List<string> source = new List<string>();

        source.Add("Default tab");
        source.Add("Voltage Tab");

        return source;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TabItemDetail> GetTabItems()
    {
        ObservableCollection<TabItemDetail> newSource = new ObservableCollection<TabItemDetail>();
        newSource.Add(new TabItemDetail { Header = "Connect" });

        return newSource;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

here is the View

```
  <Window x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleApp"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TabItemDetail}">
        <TabItem Header="{Binding Header}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataSource}"/>

    <TabControl Grid.Column="2" local:MySampleAttachedProperty.Header="{Binding SelectedDataSource}">
        <TabItem Header ="Connect" />
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

here is the new attached property class which does the trick

```
public class MySampleAttachedProperty
{
    public static string GetHeader(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHeader(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Header.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Header", typeof(string), typeof(MySampleAttachedProperty), new UIPropertyMetadata(CallBack));


    private static void CallBack(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        TabItem newTab = new TabItem { Header = args.NewValue };
        tabControl.Items.Add(newTab);
        newTab.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sandepku :) My voltage mainwindow.xaml has some Ui components. Looking at above code, it looks like a tab can be added dynamically but how will i display the Ui elements inside the Voltage tab???

Comment: Well if you look at onTabChnaged() in my above code, u will find I am able to get the selecteditem from the listbox. So the moment i select VOLTAGE from the listbox, Voltage tab shud be added into the tabcontrol which already has CONNECT item. Looking at your sample code, I may have to change the entire structure of the class. If you want I can upload the sample app that can clear the issue I am facing :)

Comment: ^ :( I am badly stuck with this. Do you want me to edit the post and add the viewmodel class and xaml here???

Comment: Basically I just need to update the xaml and add the class as mentioned above to my project. I will keep the viewmodel class as it was when i posted the question

Comment: Well I tried it. still unsuccessful :( Actually the idea of adding tabs needs to be done after few initial steps which I have done in my code. I am sure you will be able to figure out the scenario oly if u look thru few lines of my code. Is there any way I can mail you the sampple app if you dont mind? It will be really helpful brother :(

Comment: Done. I added my viewmodel class and the .xaml file :) Hope its clear now. let me know if u are not able to trace

Comment: U can c on startup, Connecttab is shown which contains listview + 3 buttons. Thus on selecting item(Bavaria, Disconnected) from LISTVIEW and clicking CONNECT button, My ListBOx towards left side gets updated with items as given in (saveexecuted method). Immediately after that when I select Voltage in my ListBox, I want Voltage tab to be added next to Connecttab. Voltage tab should have the view of my Voltage.xaml file which is present towards the end of the question :)

Comment: OnTabChnaged() should add the voltage tab since (Selectedtab.tabOperation == "Voltage"), just tell me how can we add a tab inside this method. Plus the same tab should reflect the UI components present in voltage.xaml file :)

Comment: what is happening if you add the attached property to the tabControl as per the code what I had shown? you will get a callback and you can add the tab in the callback.. try adding the local:MySampleAttachedProperty.Header="{Binding SelectedItem}" to the code and then the attached property file

Comment: It is adding tab but oly once. i.e. if i click VOLTAGE, it adds tab, then if i click "Clock" it does not add a tab. So at one time only one tab gets added. How to make sure on any selected item tab shud get created one after the another?

Comment: this should not be the case since its bound to the selectedItem.. can you put a breakpoint in the callback method in the attached property class and check whether its getting called or not?

Comment: Added breakpoint, it gets called only the first time I select the item. The remaining items once selected doesnt call callback method

Comment: is it bound to the selecteditem or not? if yes it should add get a callback

Comment: Here is the issue where name of the tab name is not appearing: "where item.Header == selectedItem" Header is string but Selecteditem is Product in my code. How can we solve this?

Comment: Well i did a lil of R&D and could figure out that the control is not entering the if condition inside AddItemsToTab(). Ur attached property adds the tab without any dependency and just based on one item in listbox. Anyway to make sure control enters if condition???